# AWS lambda "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named >'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'" using langchain and lambda layers

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pydantic, aws-lambda-layers, py-langchain

### **Context**

I have a lambda with the following handler function:

```
import json
from langchain_community.llms import ollama

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from LLM Lambda!')
    }
```

I have a .venv active and ran `pip install langchain` and then running `pip list` on my local I get:

```
aiohttp             3.9.1
aiosignal           1.3.1
annotated-types     0.6.0
anyio               4.2.0
async-timeout       4.0.3
attrs               23.2.0
certifi             2023.11.17
charset-normalizer  3.3.2
dataclasses-json    0.6.3
exceptiongroup      1.2.0
frozenlist          1.4.1
greenlet            3.0.3
idna                3.6
jsonpatch           1.33
jsonpointer         2.4
langchain           0.1.3
langchain-community 0.0.15
langchain-core      0.1.15
langsmith           0.0.83
marshmallow         3.20.2
multidict           6.0.4
mypy-extensions     1.0.0
numpy               1.26.3
packaging           23.2
pip                 23.3.2
pydantic            2.5.3
pydantic_core       2.14.6
PyYAML              6.0.1
requests            2.31.0
setuptools          58.0.4
sniffio             1.3.0
SQLAlchemy          2.0.25
tenacity            8.2.3
typing_extensions   4.9.0
typing-inspect      0.9.0
urllib3             2.1.0
yarl                1.9.4
```

As you can see the package `pydantic_core` is present.

From `.venv/lib/python3.9/sites-packages` I'm copiyng, renaming and zipping `site-packages` into `python.zip` then uploading it to an S3 bucket.

I then create a lambda layer with the following configs and referencing the mentioned zip file S3 object url like this `https://bucketname.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/lib/python.zip`

> [image]

### **THE PROBLEM**

Is that the lambda function is currently crashing with the following error message:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "7b2bba93-151f-4168-86fd-9ddad2d787fe",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

### **Notes on what I have tried:**

- If I comment out the `from langchain_community.llms import ollama` line in the lambda source code it runs without problems.
- I also tried uploading the zip file directly to the layer with the same result.
- I did the whole same process but uploading and importing the `requests` package instead of `langchain` and the lambda ran successfully.
- I'm using python 3.9 and installing packages for an x86_64 architecture.

Comment: I suggest you to use docker images to build lambda function containers to avoid these setup problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to my own problem.

Previously I was doing the `pip install` on my local environment, zipping the `sites-packages` and uploading it to S3

My local environment is a Mac.

I tested running the pip install **inside an EC2 instance**, zipping and uploading it straight to S3 and then the Lambda had no issues with any package.

I'm guessing the difference in OS between my Mac and the Lambda was making the install of `pydantic_core` break at some point.